# DATETIME Function in SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

Why does the DATEIME conversion in the SELECT statement below produce a 210056 SQL syntax error?  "act_start_dt" is a DATE type formatted as '2015-01-01' and "act_start_tm" is an integer represented number of seconds since midnight.

The statement works fine without the DATETIME call.

```
SELECT TOP 100
    act_start_dt,
    act_start_tm,
    DATETIME(act_start_dt, act_start_tm)
FROM
    PUB.MyTable;
```

The date and time columns are defined as:

```
act_start_dt[date(10) DEFAULT NULL]
act_start_tm[integer(10) DEFAULT 0]
```

Comment: You need to use a timestamp for `act_start_tm`, not just the seconds since midnight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DATETIME()` function in ProgressDB appears to take a timestamp of the following format as input:

```
2015-01-01 11:04:23
```

Use can use the `STRING` function on the `act_start_dt` and `act_start_tm` columns to get the format you need.

```
DATETIME(STRING(act_start_dt,"9999-99-99") + " " +  STRING(act_start_tm,"HH:MM:SS"))
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim, but that doesn't work either.  Same error.  In fact, even the individual STRING functions yield the same error.

Comment: Update your question with the code used to define the date columns.  Something smells fishy here.

Comment: Columns are defined as:

act_start_dt [date(10) DEFAULT NULL]
act_start_tm [integer(10) DEFAULT 0]

I also noticed that something as straightforward as DATETIME("2015-05-05 7:23:15") still errors out.  It's as if the system doesn't recognize these basic functions.  Could it be that a required function library is not installed or enabled on the server?

Comment: Hi David, sorry for not replying earlier, it seems that SO never notified me.  Yes, I think you may be missing some dependencies.  I think most of what we suggested here should be working for you.